# Graph of the function which involves Dirac Delta function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta, perturbation-theory

I am working on Modified Homotopy perturbation transformation method to solve a PDE.
Referred paper is given below.

DOI 10.1007/s10598-015-9278-x

In the above paper, they got $w(r,t)$ as
\begin{equation}
w(r,t)=f(r)*\delta(t)
\end{equation}

Where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac's delta function and $f(r)$ is some function of $r$, the exact definition of $f(r)$ can be seen in the paper. Since that is not important here, I am not mentioning it here.

Then they have given the values of $w(r,t)$ for different values of $r$ when $t=0.2$ and $t=2$.

For example when $r=1.2$ and $t=0.2$, $w(r,t)=0.834044$ and when $r=1.2$ but when $t=2$, $w(r,t)=0.855111$.

My question is how to calculate $\delta(0.2)$ and $\delta(2)$? From the above equation that I mentioned here, we can see that the values of $w(1.2,t)$ are changing for different values of $t$ only depends on $\delta(t)$. How can we find the values of Dirac delta function exactly at some point?

Comment: $\delta(t)=0$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}\land t\ne0$, so if $*$ denotes multiplication the results make no sense. If $*$ indicates convolution, then $w(r,t)=f(r)*\delta(t)=f(r)$ since $f(r)$ is not a function of $t$, so again the result makes no sense. In general $[f(t)*\delta(t)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\, \delta (x-t)\,dt=f(x)$. Are you sure $f(r)$ is not a function of $t$ as well as $r$?

Comment: Yes. $f(r)$ does not contains any $t$ term. Also * is not convolution, usual multiplication. They applied Laplace transformation to the PDE, and then while applying inverse Laplace, they are getting $L^{-1}(1)=\delta(t)$ which is multiplied to some function of $r$ only.

Comment: If $*$ is normal multiplication and $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function, then $\delta(0.2)=\delta(2)=0$ so the results make no sense.

Comment: Since the paper is behind a paywall you will have to type up all of the relevant calculation including definitions if you want an answer. There is some context you are definitely missing.